# Prevent RecyclerView to load all data

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

My recyclerView is placed between two 'View' in a LinearLayout and it fills this place with weight property as below code.

My problem: When I set its height with other values but a constant number, it loads all data at first.

I test this method in the `onCreateView` method of the fragment. But it didn't work!

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

So when I put this code in my recyclerView, it works fine and loads data by scrolling:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                ...
                android:layout_height="500dp"
                ...
 />
```

But when I change to other types of value it loads all data at once. like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                ...
                android:layout_height="0dp" <!--OR wrap_content , ...-->
                android:layout_weight="1"
                ...
 />
```

I want to make a structure like this:

[image]

How can I prevent RecyclerView from this behavior?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="60"
            >

            <include
                android:id="@+id/cardindex_header"
                layout="@layout/item_customer_card_index"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/cardindex_recycler"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
                tools:listitem="@layout/item_customer_card_index" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/footer"
                layout="@layout/item_customer_card_index"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="40">

    </View>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Didn't quite get the question . Would you explain properly ?

Comment: create separate viewtype for footer/header

Comment: @ADM I put extra information about my problem

Comment: What do you mean by loading data at once? Do you have an `Endless RecyclerView` which load more data by scrolling? Can we see some java code?

Comment: @AntonKazakov I know I can do it. I'm looking for a solution that RecyclerView with dynamic height which not load all data at once

Comment: @ Hamed Momeni it means that it loads all data at first which cause performance of fragment loading falls down. RecyclerView should loads data on scrolling not at once.

Comment: RecyclerView doesn't load anything. You should do the loading and it should be asynchronous to avoid screen jitters or slowing down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found a reason for the problem. However, I don't know why it happens! The problem begins with root Linear layout and it does not depend on dynamic RecyclerView height(Or maybe they related together!)

So I change my root layout and the problem fixed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/card_index_keypad"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/card_index_header"
            layout="@layout/item_customer_card_index"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/card_index_recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_customer_card_index" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/card_index_footer"
            layout="@layout/item_customer_card_index"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/card_index_keypad"
        android:layout_width="221dp"
        android:layout_height="820dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="3dp">

    </View>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add views dynamically in your Java code. Or create separate ViewTypes for your header/footer.

Comment: I cannot use this solution. because I want header and footer be fixed in their place and only recyclerview scrolls to show its own data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RelativeLayout for layouts with one widget lying below, above, on right and on left of another widget. Here is what I would do for a similar problem.

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/main_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/photo_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/text2"/>
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/text2"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="50dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Similarly you can use android android:layout_toRightOf and android:layout_toLeftOf.

First create a RelativeLayout for whole screen
Than make the Right most LinearLayout and align it right.
Now create the Left most LinearLayout and use attribute android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/[ID OF RIGHT MOST LinearLayout]" 
Now add three widgets as you want one below the other inside this LinearLayout.